# Why is the movie being shot inside of La La Land using old equipment?

Tags: props, la-la-land

There is a scene in which Ryan Gosling & Emma Stone are walking along a street.  They pass by a movie that is being shot. The equipment (like lights, etc.) looks old and classic. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of equipment is still in use today. I live in a neighborhood in Los Angeles where many things are filmed. (We receive flyers from [FilmLA](https://www.filmla.com) saying there will be a shoot next Tuesday on your street and traffic will be stopped for 2 minutes at a time during shooting... etc.) I have sometimes seen lights like those being used in the last 5 years. I don't think they usually shoot with actual film, but I don't often see the cameras.

Comment: Yeah, we were still using these lights at school, too... the new LEDs are starting to take over but they're really expensive.